# Regex filtering Regex, extra additional final \r

Tags: c#, regex

I want to filter a *regex* with a ... *regex* ...

My target is in a file which content is

...
information 1...
Entity1=^\|1[\s\t]+[\S]+[\s\t]+(.*)$
information 2...
...

The file is transferred to *mystring* with the method *ReadAllText(path);* where path is the path to the text file.

I use the code

```cs
//Retrieve regex like ^\|1[\s\t]+[\S]+[\s\t]+(.*)$ in Entity1=^\|1[\s\t]+[\S]+[\s\t]+(.*)$
//\d for any digit followed by =
// . for any character found 1 or + times, ended with space character
m = Regex.Match(mystring, @"Entity\d=(.+)\s");
string regex = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

which works almost fine

What I get is ( seen from inside the degugger )

> ^\|1[\s\t]+[\S]+[\s\t]+(.*)$\r

There is an additional **\r** at the end of the result. It causes an unwanted extra newline in other parts of the code.

Trying @"Entity\d=(.+)" (i.e removing the final \s) does not help.

Any idea of how to avoid the additionnal \r gracefully ( I do not want,if possible, to track the finale \r and remove it )

Online regex tester like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) did not permit to foresee this problem before going to C# code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negated character class to make sure `\r` is not matched:

```
m = Regex.Match(mystring, @"Entity\d=([^\r\n]+)");
```

The `[^\r\n]` class means *match any character other than a carriage return and a line feed*.

It is true that regex101 does not keep carriage returns. You can see the `\r` matching at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
@"Entity\d=(.+)(?=(\r|\n))";
```

`(?=(\r|\n))` is a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and means that the `\r` or `\n`  won't be included in the result.

Edit:

```
@"Entity\d=(.+?)(?=\r|\n)";
```

Comment: This is certainly an alternative, although it costs some performance points for the dot greedy matching with a look-ahead containing an alternation (=much redundant backtracking).

Comment: correction of my comment: Your first proposal @"Entity\d=(.+)(?=\r)" was working but @"Entity\d=(.+)(?=(\r|\n))" is not working, the additionnal \r is still there.